# Recommendations as to how to seal or protect brand new leather seats?

Tags: interior

My wife just bought a new Subaru Outback with leather seats. We said "no" at that point in the transaction when they try to sell you $1000 of interior / exterior protection, but now we are faced with doing some protection ourselves, especially of the interior and especially of the leather.

Any recommendations as to how to seal or protect these brand new leather seats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the seats clean and use a good leather conditioner on the parts of the seats that are actually leather so it doesn't dry out. Don't bother with "protective" chemicals, just look after the seats. Japanese leather seats are generally fairly well sealed anyway, so putting more sealant on top isn't going to help.

The "keep them clean" part is probably the most important one - grinding dirt and dust that gets on the seats in is what is going to do the most damage in the long term.